# Paypal Payflow Fraud Transaction - (Carding) on Magento 2.2.2

Tags: magento2.2, payment-methods, transaction, paypal-payflow-pro

My website is running on **Magento 2.2.2** and I am using **Paypal Payflow** as a `payment method`.

The issue that we are facing is someone with different `IP addresses` is using our website for [Carding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carding_(fraud)) and my `PayPal account` has been deactivated. They are saying that your account is getting `suspicious transactions` Until you will not fix this issue we will not enable your account.

Please suggest me a solution so that I would be able to re-open my `PayPal account`. I would really appreciate your help and consideration.

Please let me know if you need any other details.

Comment: Did you find a good solution to this, I am getting the same problem right now!

Comment: I didn't find a solution yet but I am blocking manually these requests using PHP code.

Comment: @nb171994 https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/268240/carding-attack-on-website/268425#268425 here I've explained a solution provided by Magento

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Carding attack on website](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/268240/carding-attack-on-website)

Answer (score 0):

This is a big issue.  Paypal shut us down for an hour yesterday until we could get a handle on blocking the IPs.  We really need a solution for this.

I wrote this to monitor the url they were hitting 35k times. Just put it in a cron job.

```
<?php
    $count =  exec('grep "/paypal/transparent/requestSecureToken/" /var/log/apache2/access.log | wc -l');
    echo $count;
    if($count > 50)
    {
            $msg = gethostname() . "  has a high count of paypal hits: " . $count;
            $msg = wordwrap($msg,70);
            mail("someone@somewhere.com", "CRITICAL Paypal Issue", $msg);
    }
    else
    {
    #       $msg = "All Good";
    #       mail("someone@somewhere.com", "CRITICAL Paypal Issue", $msg);

    }
```

?>

Comment: This does not really provide an answer to the question. Once you will have enough reputation you will have the possibility to leave comments.